# Wordpress - How to create a custom functions.php file in another folder?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've seen some tutorials about creating files like `my_functions.php`, and also `custom_functions.php`, but all for specific themes. What I'm looking for is a way to create a custom `functions.php` file that can be used in any theme, is it possible? At least a plugin or put the original file in a different folder. I don't know, I've been looking everywhere and I can't find anything.

Comment: Then you should create a plugin. There is no way to make a functions file inside a theme available to other themes. That is what plugins are meant to do :-)

Comment: Is there a way to create another folder inside my theme for the file?

Comment: Yes, simply create a file as you would do with `functions.php`, call it what you like and use `require_once in `functions.php` to call this new file. But remember, that code will only work on that specific theme, and some functionalities are better suited for plugins (like custom post types and custom taxonomies which should **always** be in a plugin) and other should go into `functions.php` (like adding theme support for thumbnails)

Comment: But won't I lose functions.php on uptade?

Comment: Yes, you will. You should either create a plugin or child theme if this is a commercial theme.